# SVG's width and height in illustrator

Tags: svg, height, width, adobe-illustrator

When saving a svg the file's width and height seem to jump all over the place. Im on CC Illustrator. Version 19.2.1. My documents height is 200px X 200px but when I display the image on my site it appears more like 500px x 500px. Can someone point me in the right direction so my width and height are taken from the artboard and or documents size. Where does this intrinsic height and width inherit from, if not from there!?

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"         viewBox="0 0 118.95486 24"><title>ic_logo</title><path d="M14.64137,5.01282a7.39107,7.39107,0,0,0-3.81278,1.08052A5.05914,5.05914,0,0,0,7.58112,5.01282a12.76456,12.76456,0,0,0-4.25247.73028,4.25836,4.25836,0,0,0-1.406-.50759,1.36127,1.36127,0,0,0-.25875-0.02535,1.10723,1.10723,0,0,0-1.12328.89861A1.17433,1.17433,0,0,0,1.479,7.41057a0.876,0.876,0,0,1,.8021.94728V9.40279c-0.00016.04206-.00016,0.08473,0,0.126V17.514a1.17042,1.17042,0,0,0,1.21525,1.14777A1.17042,1.17042,0,0,0,4.71154,17.514V7.58224a9.91505,9.91505,0,0,1,2.86958-.39939c1.063,0,2.13892.50964,2.13892,1.48385V17.514a1.203,1.203,0,0,0,2.40342,0V7.89926a4.76825,4.76825,0,0,1,2.51792-.71641,2.40839,2.40839,0,0,1,2.49058,2.311V17.514a1.21728,1.21728,0,0,0,2.43059,0V9.61918A4.7769,4.7769,0,0,0,14.64137,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#00a7e1"/><path d="M30.55163,5.01282a1.20718,1.20718,0,0,0-1.14651.80524l-2.93155,8.9768L23.06381,5.77837a1.1959,1.1959,0,0,0-1.1414-.74067,1.16985,1.16985,0,0,0-1.21533,1.14777,1.06384,1.06384,0,0,0,.05141.306l0.01693,0.06189,4.48486,11.56982-0.61515,1.85238a2.75686,2.75686,0,0,1-2.79194,1.80481,1.16992,1.16992,0,0,0-1.173,1.09705A1.131,1.131,0,0,0,21.8684,24,5.09081,5.09081,0,0,0,26.909,20.66694L31.72421,6.53147l0.01851-.06457a1.07119,1.07119,0,0,0,.05133-0.30646A1.19921,1.19921,0,0,0,30.55163,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#00a7e1"/><path d="M38.62989,5.01282a7.104,7.104,0,0,0-2.81516.584v-4.449a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0-2.43051,0V17.514a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0,2.43051,0V8.15266a4.45818,4.45818,0,0,1,2.81516-.96981c1.77205,0,2.78839.94272,2.78839,2.58658V17.514a1.2172,1.2172,0,0,0,2.43043,0V9.89462C43.84871,6.97465,41.75152,5.01282,38.62989,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M80.08725,5.01282a7.389,7.389,0,0,0-3.81262,1.08052,5.06045,5.06045,0,0,0-3.24771-1.08052,12.76574,12.76574,0,0,0-4.25233.73028,4.25965,4.25965,0,0,0-1.40588-.50759,1.36243,1.36243,0,0,0-.25891-0.02535,1.10687,1.10687,0,0,0-1.123.89861,1.17375,1.17375,0,0,0,.93832,1.3018,0.87591,0.87591,0,0,1,.80192.94728V17.514a1.21732,1.21732,0,0,0,2.43067,0V7.58224a9.91332,9.91332,0,0,1,2.86927-.39939c1.06288,0,2.13914.50964,2.13914,1.48385V17.514a1.203,1.203,0,0,0,2.40343,0V7.89926a4.76727,4.76727,0,0,1,2.51775-.71641,2.40871,2.40871,0,0,1,2.49082,2.311V17.514a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0,2.43051,0V9.61918A4.777,4.777,0,0,0,80.08725,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M92.38545,5.01282c-3.13778,0-5.24592,1.96183-5.24592,4.8818v3.88506c0,2.92015,2.10814,4.88213,5.24592,4.88213a9.60258,9.60258,0,0,0,3.99232-.82933,1.11725,1.11725,0,0,0,.68539-1.02021A1.14839,1.14839,0,0,0,95.848,15.71489a1.32013,1.32013,0,0,0-.49135.09734,7.73685,7.73685,0,0,1-2.97117.6794,2.56513,2.56513,0,0,1-2.81524-2.712V12.67161h6.46708a1.52419,1.52419,0,0,0,1.567-1.47361V9.89462C97.60429,6.97465,95.50686,5.01282,92.38545,5.01282ZM89.57021,9.76943c0-1.64386,1.02619-2.58658,2.81524-2.58658,1.77175,0,2.78816.94272,2.78816,2.58658v0.732H89.57021v-0.732Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M100.30268,15.63963a1.51325,1.51325,0,1,0,0,3.02218,1.57639,1.57639,0,0,0,1.62087-1.52354A1.5464,1.5464,0,0,0,100.30268,15.63963Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M105.08116,0a1.47177,1.47177,0,0,0-1.51251,1.42336,1.51426,1.51426,0,0,0,3.02567,0A1.47213,1.47213,0,0,0,105.08116,0Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M105.08116,5.01282A1.199,1.199,0,0,0,103.866,6.16044V17.514a1.21732,1.21732,0,0,0,2.43067,0V6.16044A1.19885,1.19885,0,0,0,105.08116,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M114.25859,5.01282c-3.13746,0-5.24559,1.96183-5.24559,4.8818v3.88506c0,2.92015,2.10814,4.88213,5.24559,4.88213a9.60515,9.60515,0,0,0,3.99264-.82933,1.11745,1.11745,0,0,0,.68506-1.02021,1.14819,1.14819,0,0,0-1.21518-1.09738,1.32013,1.32013,0,0,0-.49135.09734,7.73685,7.73685,0,0,1-2.97117.6794,2.56529,2.56529,0,0,1-2.81524-2.712V12.67161h6.46708a1.524,1.524,0,0,0,1.567-1.47361V9.89462C119.47743,6.97465,117.38033,5.01282,114.25859,5.01282Zm-2.81524,4.75661c0-1.64386,1.02619-2.58658,2.81524-2.58658,1.77205,0,2.78817.94272,2.78817,2.58658v0.732h-5.60341v-0.732Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M65.431,8.878a6.49719,6.49719,0,0,0-.52286-1.92726,5.55933,5.55933,0,0,0-2.06877-2.41011,6.39345,6.39345,0,0,0-2.67028-.96847A8.09851,8.09851,0,0,0,58.62,3.5015c-0.30065.01574-.60019,0.04228-0.89831,0.08408a11.00211,11.00211,0,0,0-1.69473.38412,0.16906,0.16906,0,0,1-.16277-0.02434c-0.11158-.07771-0.22655-0.15064-0.34206-0.22207A7.8283,7.8283,0,0,0,51.825,2.53972a7.01465,7.01465,0,0,0-2.74406.37837,6.911,6.911,0,0,0-2.957,1.93418,5.5805,5.5805,0,0,0-1.05108,1.71016,6.67114,6.67114,0,0,0-.42144,2.50076,8.30327,8.30327,0,0,0,.14583,1.60353,13.46922,13.46922,0,0,0,.95036,3.065,12.97616,12.97616,0,0,0,3.47583,4.73155,9.44966,9.44966,0,0,0,3.4374,1.90434,0.46921,0.46921,0,0,0,.15214.02127c0.37048-.01071.74106-0.01969,1.11076-0.05749a10.19807,10.19807,0,0,0,1.824-.35214,15.82843,15.82843,0,0,0,3.7405-1.62464,16.08089,16.08089,0,0,0,3.33606-2.62319,11.21014,11.21014,0,0,0,1.8508-2.51327,6.94,6.94,0,0,0,.83467-3.18692A8.83971,8.83971,0,0,0,65.431,8.878Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#16a7e0" fill-rule="evenodd"/><polygon points="47.951 14.186 58.717 15.644 59.809 9.403 55.225 6.053 49.18 8.005 47.951 14.186" fill="#fff"/></svg>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could show a (small-ish) example svg file from Illustrator along with a description of the exact unexpected behaviour for that example. From what you've described so far, I'm wondering whether the issue might have something to do with the viewBox parameter on the svg root element.

Comment: Added some imaged to help illustrate. The artboard is cropped and the saved image to the right has a large height. Should it not take its height from the file?

Comment: It definitely helps to see an image of the graphics. However, looking at a bit-map image of code is very frustrating on a helping web site like this: If want to find out, e.g., where your `path` elements start, or even simply how many there are, I have to actually _read_ the entire svg file. I (and 99% of others) would rather do a quick "find" for, say, "path". So, please, copy and paste the actual svg code. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry new to stack overflow is that ok?

Comment: Yes. I can take a better look at it now.

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows that the `svg` root element has no `width` and `height` attributes on it, but does have a `viewBox` attribute on it. The `viewBox` is a powerful tool for zooming and positioning your svg image, but it can also be a little confusing. If you want more information, I've found [this tutorial](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) helpful.

In any case, to simplify your situation, you can delete the `viewBox` attribute and include `width` and `height` attributes that you want. The first code snippet below shows the svg code as you provided it. The second shows the same code with the attribute changes I mentioned.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"         viewBox="0 0 118.95486 24"><title>ic_logo</title><path d="M14.64137,5.01282a7.39107,7.39107,0,0,0-3.81278,1.08052A5.05914,5.05914,0,0,0,7.58112,5.01282a12.76456,12.76456,0,0,0-4.25247.73028,4.25836,4.25836,0,0,0-1.406-.50759,1.36127,1.36127,0,0,0-.25875-0.02535,1.10723,1.10723,0,0,0-1.12328.89861A1.17433,1.17433,0,0,0,1.479,7.41057a0.876,0.876,0,0,1,.8021.94728V9.40279c-0.00016.04206-.00016,0.08473,0,0.126V17.514a1.17042,1.17042,0,0,0,1.21525,1.14777A1.17042,1.17042,0,0,0,4.71154,17.514V7.58224a9.91505,9.91505,0,0,1,2.86958-.39939c1.063,0,2.13892.50964,2.13892,1.48385V17.514a1.203,1.203,0,0,0,2.40342,0V7.89926a4.76825,4.76825,0,0,1,2.51792-.71641,2.40839,2.40839,0,0,1,2.49058,2.311V17.514a1.21728,1.21728,0,0,0,2.43059,0V9.61918A4.7769,4.7769,0,0,0,14.64137,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#00a7e1"/><path d="M30.55163,5.01282a1.20718,1.20718,0,0,0-1.14651.80524l-2.93155,8.9768L23.06381,5.77837a1.1959,1.1959,0,0,0-1.1414-.74067,1.16985,1.16985,0,0,0-1.21533,1.14777,1.06384,1.06384,0,0,0,.05141.306l0.01693,0.06189,4.48486,11.56982-0.61515,1.85238a2.75686,2.75686,0,0,1-2.79194,1.80481,1.16992,1.16992,0,0,0-1.173,1.09705A1.131,1.131,0,0,0,21.8684,24,5.09081,5.09081,0,0,0,26.909,20.66694L31.72421,6.53147l0.01851-.06457a1.07119,1.07119,0,0,0,.05133-0.30646A1.19921,1.19921,0,0,0,30.55163,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#00a7e1"/><path d="M38.62989,5.01282a7.104,7.104,0,0,0-2.81516.584v-4.449a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0-2.43051,0V17.514a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0,2.43051,0V8.15266a4.45818,4.45818,0,0,1,2.81516-.96981c1.77205,0,2.78839.94272,2.78839,2.58658V17.514a1.2172,1.2172,0,0,0,2.43043,0V9.89462C43.84871,6.97465,41.75152,5.01282,38.62989,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M80.08725,5.01282a7.389,7.389,0,0,0-3.81262,1.08052,5.06045,5.06045,0,0,0-3.24771-1.08052,12.76574,12.76574,0,0,0-4.25233.73028,4.25965,4.25965,0,0,0-1.40588-.50759,1.36243,1.36243,0,0,0-.25891-0.02535,1.10687,1.10687,0,0,0-1.123.89861,1.17375,1.17375,0,0,0,.93832,1.3018,0.87591,0.87591,0,0,1,.80192.94728V17.514a1.21732,1.21732,0,0,0,2.43067,0V7.58224a9.91332,9.91332,0,0,1,2.86927-.39939c1.06288,0,2.13914.50964,2.13914,1.48385V17.514a1.203,1.203,0,0,0,2.40343,0V7.89926a4.76727,4.76727,0,0,1,2.51775-.71641,2.40871,2.40871,0,0,1,2.49082,2.311V17.514a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0,2.43051,0V9.61918A4.777,4.777,0,0,0,80.08725,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M92.38545,5.01282c-3.13778,0-5.24592,1.96183-5.24592,4.8818v3.88506c0,2.92015,2.10814,4.88213,5.24592,4.88213a9.60258,9.60258,0,0,0,3.99232-.82933,1.11725,1.11725,0,0,0,.68539-1.02021A1.14839,1.14839,0,0,0,95.848,15.71489a1.32013,1.32013,0,0,0-.49135.09734,7.73685,7.73685,0,0,1-2.97117.6794,2.56513,2.56513,0,0,1-2.81524-2.712V12.67161h6.46708a1.52419,1.52419,0,0,0,1.567-1.47361V9.89462C97.60429,6.97465,95.50686,5.01282,92.38545,5.01282ZM89.57021,9.76943c0-1.64386,1.02619-2.58658,2.81524-2.58658,1.77175,0,2.78816.94272,2.78816,2.58658v0.732H89.57021v-0.732Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M100.30268,15.63963a1.51325,1.51325,0,1,0,0,3.02218,1.57639,1.57639,0,0,0,1.62087-1.52354A1.5464,1.5464,0,0,0,100.30268,15.63963Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M105.08116,0a1.47177,1.47177,0,0,0-1.51251,1.42336,1.51426,1.51426,0,0,0,3.02567,0A1.47213,1.47213,0,0,0,105.08116,0Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M105.08116,5.01282A1.199,1.199,0,0,0,103.866,6.16044V17.514a1.21732,1.21732,0,0,0,2.43067,0V6.16044A1.19885,1.19885,0,0,0,105.08116,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M114.25859,5.01282c-3.13746,0-5.24559,1.96183-5.24559,4.8818v3.88506c0,2.92015,2.10814,4.88213,5.24559,4.88213a9.60515,9.60515,0,0,0,3.99264-.82933,1.11745,1.11745,0,0,0,.68506-1.02021,1.14819,1.14819,0,0,0-1.21518-1.09738,1.32013,1.32013,0,0,0-.49135.09734,7.73685,7.73685,0,0,1-2.97117.6794,2.56529,2.56529,0,0,1-2.81524-2.712V12.67161h6.46708a1.524,1.524,0,0,0,1.567-1.47361V9.89462C119.47743,6.97465,117.38033,5.01282,114.25859,5.01282Zm-2.81524,4.75661c0-1.64386,1.02619-2.58658,2.81524-2.58658,1.77205,0,2.78817.94272,2.78817,2.58658v0.732h-5.60341v-0.732Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M65.431,8.878a6.49719,6.49719,0,0,0-.52286-1.92726,5.55933,5.55933,0,0,0-2.06877-2.41011,6.39345,6.39345,0,0,0-2.67028-.96847A8.09851,8.09851,0,0,0,58.62,3.5015c-0.30065.01574-.60019,0.04228-0.89831,0.08408a11.00211,11.00211,0,0,0-1.69473.38412,0.16906,0.16906,0,0,1-.16277-0.02434c-0.11158-.07771-0.22655-0.15064-0.34206-0.22207A7.8283,7.8283,0,0,0,51.825,2.53972a7.01465,7.01465,0,0,0-2.74406.37837,6.911,6.911,0,0,0-2.957,1.93418,5.5805,5.5805,0,0,0-1.05108,1.71016,6.67114,6.67114,0,0,0-.42144,2.50076,8.30327,8.30327,0,0,0,.14583,1.60353,13.46922,13.46922,0,0,0,.95036,3.065,12.97616,12.97616,0,0,0,3.47583,4.73155,9.44966,9.44966,0,0,0,3.4374,1.90434,0.46921,0.46921,0,0,0,.15214.02127c0.37048-.01071.74106-0.01969,1.11076-0.05749a10.19807,10.19807,0,0,0,1.824-.35214,15.82843,15.82843,0,0,0,3.7405-1.62464,16.08089,16.08089,0,0,0,3.33606-2.62319,11.21014,11.21014,0,0,0,1.8508-2.51327,6.94,6.94,0,0,0,.83467-3.18692A8.83971,8.83971,0,0,0,65.431,8.878Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#16a7e0" fill-rule="evenodd"/><polygon points="47.951 14.186 58.717 15.644 59.809 9.403 55.225 6.053 49.18 8.005 47.951 14.186" fill="#fff"/></svg>
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200"><title>ic_logo</title><path d="M14.64137,5.01282a7.39107,7.39107,0,0,0-3.81278,1.08052A5.05914,5.05914,0,0,0,7.58112,5.01282a12.76456,12.76456,0,0,0-4.25247.73028,4.25836,4.25836,0,0,0-1.406-.50759,1.36127,1.36127,0,0,0-.25875-0.02535,1.10723,1.10723,0,0,0-1.12328.89861A1.17433,1.17433,0,0,0,1.479,7.41057a0.876,0.876,0,0,1,.8021.94728V9.40279c-0.00016.04206-.00016,0.08473,0,0.126V17.514a1.17042,1.17042,0,0,0,1.21525,1.14777A1.17042,1.17042,0,0,0,4.71154,17.514V7.58224a9.91505,9.91505,0,0,1,2.86958-.39939c1.063,0,2.13892.50964,2.13892,1.48385V17.514a1.203,1.203,0,0,0,2.40342,0V7.89926a4.76825,4.76825,0,0,1,2.51792-.71641,2.40839,2.40839,0,0,1,2.49058,2.311V17.514a1.21728,1.21728,0,0,0,2.43059,0V9.61918A4.7769,4.7769,0,0,0,14.64137,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#00a7e1"/><path d="M30.55163,5.01282a1.20718,1.20718,0,0,0-1.14651.80524l-2.93155,8.9768L23.06381,5.77837a1.1959,1.1959,0,0,0-1.1414-.74067,1.16985,1.16985,0,0,0-1.21533,1.14777,1.06384,1.06384,0,0,0,.05141.306l0.01693,0.06189,4.48486,11.56982-0.61515,1.85238a2.75686,2.75686,0,0,1-2.79194,1.80481,1.16992,1.16992,0,0,0-1.173,1.09705A1.131,1.131,0,0,0,21.8684,24,5.09081,5.09081,0,0,0,26.909,20.66694L31.72421,6.53147l0.01851-.06457a1.07119,1.07119,0,0,0,.05133-0.30646A1.19921,1.19921,0,0,0,30.55163,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#00a7e1"/><path d="M38.62989,5.01282a7.104,7.104,0,0,0-2.81516.584v-4.449a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0-2.43051,0V17.514a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0,2.43051,0V8.15266a4.45818,4.45818,0,0,1,2.81516-.96981c1.77205,0,2.78839.94272,2.78839,2.58658V17.514a1.2172,1.2172,0,0,0,2.43043,0V9.89462C43.84871,6.97465,41.75152,5.01282,38.62989,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M80.08725,5.01282a7.389,7.389,0,0,0-3.81262,1.08052,5.06045,5.06045,0,0,0-3.24771-1.08052,12.76574,12.76574,0,0,0-4.25233.73028,4.25965,4.25965,0,0,0-1.40588-.50759,1.36243,1.36243,0,0,0-.25891-0.02535,1.10687,1.10687,0,0,0-1.123.89861,1.17375,1.17375,0,0,0,.93832,1.3018,0.87591,0.87591,0,0,1,.80192.94728V17.514a1.21732,1.21732,0,0,0,2.43067,0V7.58224a9.91332,9.91332,0,0,1,2.86927-.39939c1.06288,0,2.13914.50964,2.13914,1.48385V17.514a1.203,1.203,0,0,0,2.40343,0V7.89926a4.76727,4.76727,0,0,1,2.51775-.71641,2.40871,2.40871,0,0,1,2.49082,2.311V17.514a1.21724,1.21724,0,0,0,2.43051,0V9.61918A4.777,4.777,0,0,0,80.08725,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M92.38545,5.01282c-3.13778,0-5.24592,1.96183-5.24592,4.8818v3.88506c0,2.92015,2.10814,4.88213,5.24592,4.88213a9.60258,9.60258,0,0,0,3.99232-.82933,1.11725,1.11725,0,0,0,.68539-1.02021A1.14839,1.14839,0,0,0,95.848,15.71489a1.32013,1.32013,0,0,0-.49135.09734,7.73685,7.73685,0,0,1-2.97117.6794,2.56513,2.56513,0,0,1-2.81524-2.712V12.67161h6.46708a1.52419,1.52419,0,0,0,1.567-1.47361V9.89462C97.60429,6.97465,95.50686,5.01282,92.38545,5.01282ZM89.57021,9.76943c0-1.64386,1.02619-2.58658,2.81524-2.58658,1.77175,0,2.78816.94272,2.78816,2.58658v0.732H89.57021v-0.732Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M100.30268,15.63963a1.51325,1.51325,0,1,0,0,3.02218,1.57639,1.57639,0,0,0,1.62087-1.52354A1.5464,1.5464,0,0,0,100.30268,15.63963Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M105.08116,0a1.47177,1.47177,0,0,0-1.51251,1.42336,1.51426,1.51426,0,0,0,3.02567,0A1.47213,1.47213,0,0,0,105.08116,0Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M105.08116,5.01282A1.199,1.199,0,0,0,103.866,6.16044V17.514a1.21732,1.21732,0,0,0,2.43067,0V6.16044A1.19885,1.19885,0,0,0,105.08116,5.01282Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M114.25859,5.01282c-3.13746,0-5.24559,1.96183-5.24559,4.8818v3.88506c0,2.92015,2.10814,4.88213,5.24559,4.88213a9.60515,9.60515,0,0,0,3.99264-.82933,1.11745,1.11745,0,0,0,.68506-1.02021,1.14819,1.14819,0,0,0-1.21518-1.09738,1.32013,1.32013,0,0,0-.49135.09734,7.73685,7.73685,0,0,1-2.97117.6794,2.56529,2.56529,0,0,1-2.81524-2.712V12.67161h6.46708a1.524,1.524,0,0,0,1.567-1.47361V9.89462C119.47743,6.97465,117.38033,5.01282,114.25859,5.01282Zm-2.81524,4.75661c0-1.64386,1.02619-2.58658,2.81524-2.58658,1.77205,0,2.78817.94272,2.78817,2.58658v0.732h-5.60341v-0.732Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#231f20"/><path d="M65.431,8.878a6.49719,6.49719,0,0,0-.52286-1.92726,5.55933,5.55933,0,0,0-2.06877-2.41011,6.39345,6.39345,0,0,0-2.67028-.96847A8.09851,8.09851,0,0,0,58.62,3.5015c-0.30065.01574-.60019,0.04228-0.89831,0.08408a11.00211,11.00211,0,0,0-1.69473.38412,0.16906,0.16906,0,0,1-.16277-0.02434c-0.11158-.07771-0.22655-0.15064-0.34206-0.22207A7.8283,7.8283,0,0,0,51.825,2.53972a7.01465,7.01465,0,0,0-2.74406.37837,6.911,6.911,0,0,0-2.957,1.93418,5.5805,5.5805,0,0,0-1.05108,1.71016,6.67114,6.67114,0,0,0-.42144,2.50076,8.30327,8.30327,0,0,0,.14583,1.60353,13.46922,13.46922,0,0,0,.95036,3.065,12.97616,12.97616,0,0,0,3.47583,4.73155,9.44966,9.44966,0,0,0,3.4374,1.90434,0.46921,0.46921,0,0,0,.15214.02127c0.37048-.01071.74106-0.01969,1.11076-0.05749a10.19807,10.19807,0,0,0,1.824-.35214,15.82843,15.82843,0,0,0,3.7405-1.62464,16.08089,16.08089,0,0,0,3.33606-2.62319,11.21014,11.21014,0,0,0,1.8508-2.51327,6.94,6.94,0,0,0,.83467-3.18692A8.83971,8.83971,0,0,0,65.431,8.878Z" transform="translate(-0.52257)" fill="#16a7e0" fill-rule="evenodd"/><polygon points="47.951 14.186 58.717 15.644 59.809 9.403 55.225 6.053 49.18 8.005 47.951 14.186" fill="#fff"/></svg>
```

Comment: Oh good man, so the width and height are not assigned but replaced by a viewbox, Thanks!

Comment: Actually you can use all three (width, height and viewBox) simultaneously if you need to.